# How can i add the JPanel class into JFrame form class in netbeans?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I created two classes in netbeans;One of them is a JPanel form and another is a JFrame form;
How can i add the JPanel class into JFrame form class?
I wrote this code in constructor of JFrame form Class but ,it didnt work.

```
public JFrameClass() {
        initComponents();
        this.getContentPane().add(jpc = new JPanelClass());
        jpc.setVisible(true);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);

    }
```

Comment: *"didnt work."*  What did you expect to happen?  What happened instead? For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: try some basic java tutorials first. `this.getContentPane().add(jpc = new JPanelClass());`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

set the bounds  of the JPanel so that the container knows where to draw it

```
       public void run() {
            NewJFrame frame = new NewJFrame();
            NewJPanel panel = new NewJPanel();

            panel.setBounds(0, 0, 200, 200);
            frame.add(panel);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
```

Comment: Calling `setBounds` is going to cause problems later.  Use layouts.  Either put content into the panel to give it a 'natural non-zero size' or if it is a 'pure rendering' component, set or override the preferred size.

Comment: @Blueferi  Poor choice of answer (not that you have accepted it yet).  Your next 10 questions will be along the lines of "How do I fix my component layout?"

Comment: @Andrew Thompson  i got your advice and i used layouts ;),but at first this answer help me to find the way for solving my problem :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure the `JPanelClass` is visible from where your `JFrameClass` is.
Then do the following:

```
JPanelClass jpc = new JPanelClass()
this.getContentPane().add(jpc);
```

Also, there is no need to call `jpc.setVisible(true);`

The resulting code should be:

```
public JFrameClass() {
        initComponents();
        JPanelClass jpc = new JPanelClass()
        getContentPane().add(jpc);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can i add the JPanel class into JFrame form class in netbeans?

In your `JFrame` class just set your `JPanel` and add its to `Container`.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanelClass();
controls.add(panel);
```

Note: You should have some private void method named for example `createAndAddCompontents()` and  call it in your constructor.

```
public JFrameClass() {
   ...
   createAndAddCompontents();
}
```

Then when you want to execute your Application so in main() method you should call it similar like this:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
      YouJFrameClass initAndShowComponents = new YouJFrameClass();
      initAndShowComponents.setVisible(true);
}
    });
```

Comment: i did this: public JFrameClass() {
            initComponents();
            this.add(jpc = new JPanelClass());
            } but nothing happened: